# Heroku hangs during migrate with strange pg_advisory_unlock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm using Rails 5.1 hosted on Heroku, and I use the following command to migrate my database:

`heroku run rake db:migrate -a [my app name]`

All the migrations themselves complete correctly:

```
SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20180504164326"]]
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
Migrating to AddPinToStaff (20180519024721)
   (1.5ms)  BEGIN
== 20180519024721 AddPinToStaff: migrating ====================================
-- add_column(:staff, :pin_number, :string)
   (4.2ms)  ALTER TABLE "staff" ADD "pin_number" character varying
   -> 0.0045s
== 20180519024721 AddPinToStaff: migrated (0.0046s) ===========================
```

That's the last migration file I created, so it all seems to work. Then, this runs:

```
SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "version"  [["version", "20180519024721"]]
(2.4ms)  COMMIT
ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(1.3ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "ar_internal_metadata" ("key", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "key"  [["key", "environment"], ["value", "beta"], ["created_at", "2018-06-04 18:54:24.766405"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-04 18:54:24.766405"]]
(2.1ms)  COMMIT
(1.4ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(5988010931190918735)
```

And it hangs there at that last SELECT statement. What is `pg_advisory_unlock` and why is it running? Reading [this blog post](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/advisory-locks-in-postgres) it seems like those should be called from my application somewhere, but I can't find any similar text in my application anywhere. Please help!

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139054/local-postrges-works-but-cant-seem-to-push-to-rails-env-production-heroku

Comment: What makes you think that it's hanging on the `pg_advisory_unlock()`? The fact that it printed a duration next to the statement suggests to me that it finished. If it is hanging on some SQL statement, the [`pg_stat_activity` view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) should tell you what and why.

Answer (score 1):

`pg_advisory_unlock` is nothing but a postgresql lock that Heroku is using to obtain a transaction level lock on your database. It is not necessary that if Heroku is unable to obtain the lock the migration itself was unsuccessful. Please check if your schema contains the migrated tables, if yes, you don't need to do anything more. Edit: Your logs say the migrations were commited, which is a strong indication that the migration was indeed successful.

Otherwise, you can try dropping your database and re-creating it, then running the migrations again. If it contains important data already, use `heroku pg:backups:capture --app <name-of-app>` to backup your database, then run `rails db:drop`, `rails db:create`, and finally, `rails db:migrate` in order to run the migration again. You can restore the database using `heroku pg:backups:restore <name-of-backup> --app <name-of-app>`

Comment: You're correct; the migration is indeed successful. However, the process doesn't finish - it hangs at that unlock attempt. If it was just a migration, I wouldn't mind so much. But, I have a process that does all you're suggesting - it drops, recreates, migrates the database, but then it also runs my seed information to populate the database. This unlock issue freezes that before it can finish as well.

Comment: Does running db:seed absolutely need to be automated? If not, running it manuall every time you push to Heroku doesn't seem like a big problem.

Comment: I did finally figure out how to work around it, similar to your suggestion: by running each step manually, then cancelling the operation when it hangs at the weird advisory unlock attempt. It's just really frustrating to have this process that's worked perfectly up until now - not only for this project, but for all the other projects I've worked on - suddenly stop working because of some PG thing that no one seems to understand. It's now happening on my production Heroku application as well, though thankfully I don't need to seed that database anymore.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Maybe you can try to create a new Heroku project and push your current files there?